# Artisan Error: Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. )

Tags: laravel

I'm having problem starting my laravel installation. Whenever I type in the terminal `php artisan serve`, it throws me an error like below:

> c:\wamp\www\blog>php artisan serve Laravel development server started
>   on http://localhost:8000/
>
> [Sat Nov 05 21:18:39 2016] Failed to listen
>   on localhost:8000 (reason: An attempt was made to access a socket in a
>   way forbidden by its access permissions.)

Comment: If you're using wamp, why do you need to use artisan serve? Just serve the content through wamp.

Comment: Can you tell me in which OS are you working?

Comment: To clearify, WAMP is a webserver, php artisan serve will also run a web server. It's generally not recommended to be using both. Use only 1 at the time. Also seeing this is laravel, I would recommend using something like vagrant and homestead. If you run Windows 10 check this link to get it fully working. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3kaQDFJiis&t=187s

Comment: 2 possibilities I can think of, something is already listening on port 8000, or possibly a firewall or antivirus preventing it from listening on the port.

Answer (score 16):

1) First firewall restore to default

2) change artisan serve port using this command `php artisan serve --port=3232`

Trust me its works :)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem today. I just restarted the my machine, after that tried with the same port and it works!

Comment: It(Restarting) works for me too. Though it seems strange behavior.

Comment: restarts works for me too

Answer (score 1):

Change artisan serve port using this command

```
php artisan serve --port=####
```

instead #### you can enter your own port number.

This will work sure.!

Answer (score 1):

You need command prompt to run as administrator, that solves the problem most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your installed Laravel properly in your local machine.

When you execute `php artisan serve` , you better to run it with administrative priviledges.

In linux, I use
`sudo php artisan localhost:8888 -t public`

Make sure other requirements such as `php version` are upto date.

```
PHP >= 5.5.9
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
```

For more information refer [this document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation).

Comment: It's generally not recommended or necessary to run a web server as a  superuser.